# Spring MVC returns 406 for css and js

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I read a lot of q+a regarding the 406 error, however none of them helped in my case:

I have a Spring MVC application with this controller:

```
@Controller 
public class CalendarController extends AbstractController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/calendar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("index");
    //modelandview.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Hi User");

    return modelandview;

}
```

These are the dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Project2</groupId>
<artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                            <version>8.5.11.2</version>
                            <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jackson.version>2.8.0</jackson.version>

</properties>
<dependencies>


    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
        Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
        Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
        this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
        spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
        spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
        Container and is generally always defined -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
        Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
        DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
        spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
        and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
        Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
        JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
        Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
        web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
        Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
        Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
        TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
        the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mongodb java driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springfram ework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>



<!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>   

</dependencies>
```

And this is the servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd        
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd">

<!-- <bean id="HandlerMappping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" 
    /> <bean name="/welcome.html" class="de.teamz.welcomecontroller.WelcomeController" 
    /> <bean name="/calendar.html" class="de.teamz.welcomecontroller.CalendarController" 
    /> -->
<context:component-scan base-package="de.teamz.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="de.teamz.model" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" credentials="test:test@mongotest"></mongo:mongo-client>
<mongo:db-factory dbname="mongotest"  />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The calendar.jsp includes the resources like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
```

...

```
<spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css" var="style" />
<link href="${style}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

same applies for other css and js.

I have the resources in this structure:

[image]

When i navigate to http://localhost:8080/ProjectBackend/calendar.html only the .html is shown, no css or js is included. When i navigate to http://localhost:8080/ProjectBackend/resources/css/style.css i get this: 
[image]

Anyone knows what to do about this?

Comment: This is almost a good question but I wish you had made a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I often find the solution when I'm reducing the problem as much as is physically possible to post as a question.

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven /> shouldn't it be the first declaration in application Context ? 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet"/> in jsp